# Performance-wise, is it Necessary to Stop Drawing Textures That Aren't On Screen Anymore?

Tags: c#, xna, textures, xna-4.0, spritebatch

I pretty much put the question in the title. Would it help performance-wise if I stopped drawing targets  are aren't on the screen anymore? What I mean by this is:

```
if (textureLocation is on the screen)
{
    draw code here
}
```

Or it is so insignificant(if at all) that it doesn't matter?

Thanks,
Shyy

Comment: [horses...](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)  - have you tried to compare both cases for *your* program?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, Logically if I did I wouldn't be asking this question. It would take a somewhat extensive amount of time to add it in just to check to see if there was a difference (considering the amount of textures that I have in my game spread throughout different classes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends. Ultimately spent time comes down to 3 things: sending data to the GPU, vertex shading, and pixel shading.

If the texture is located on a spritesheet that has other textures that are being drawn on screen and the offscreen draw call is within the same `.Begin() .End()` block as those others, it won't hurt performance since it takes just as long to send data and set the GPU up for the spritesheet. The 4 off-screen vertices will run through the vertex shader but that is not a bottle neck. The graphic pipeline culls offscreen objects between the vertex shader and pixel shader so it won't spend any time in the pixel shader

But if is a stand alone texture or in it's own `.Begin() .End()` block, it will cost time sending it's data to the GPU even though the GPU will cull it.

Whether it is significant or not only profiling can tell you.

Comment: Thank you for replying! +I've selected this answer. +1